# Blue color filter for Ubuntu with multiple screen support

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, screen

I am looking for software which helps me reduce the blue light on multiple screens on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I tried Redshift and Flux but unfortunately they don't have support for multiple screens.

Edit: I am using DisplayLink to connect the external monitors

Comment: Redshift is no longer needed since the introduction of the night light feature that can be enabled in system settings > screens and should apply to all screens.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04.4 by default comes with nightlight software that supports multiple screens out of the box. Activate it in "Settings" - "Displays" - "Nightlight" tab.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that I am using DisplayLink to connect my external screens and those settings ("nightlight") don't support that configuration (despite of seening external displays in the settings)